# Cannot display attributes those in Used in Product Listing set to yes

Tags: custom-attributes, product-list, magento2.4.5p1

I created an attribute (my_text) as a text field.

In stores Attributes Product under Storefront Properties I set Used in Product Listing to Yes. However, the attribute is not displayed on the category page.
On the other hand, Used for Sorting in Product Listing is available with "Yes".

How do I get the attribute displayed on the category page in the pruoduct listing for each product?

Answer (score 0):

Please execute below commands on magento root path & check. This commands require when your application set on default or production mode.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I had already tried that. Unfortunately it's no use.